# Windows 7 just restarts, no BSOD, shows "Event ID 14 volsnap"

Tags: windows-7, ssd, crash, bsod, event-viewer

My Windows 7 just restarts without giving me a BSOD.

When it reboots, it will hang sometimes and you have to let it rest. Sometimes it will print a message saying that `Hal.dll` is missing or corrupt. When it does restart I can't run a backup or a clone drive – it comes up with constant errors.

I tried to run `chkdsk` – it says everything's clean.

What is really puzzling is SyncToy on a different drive hangs half way through and won't run either.

Machine:

- OCZ SSD Agility 2 for C drive
- SATA HDD for programs, documents on D drive
- MSI AMD 880 chipset

Event viewer says something about critical power failure I/O operations and "Event ID 14 volsnap" – but that is just telling me the computer powered off which I already know.

Comment: There might be some hardware fault. The errors seem to point it to the disk and the cables to the disks. It can also be memory or CPU. I would do some system stress test under an OS on a USB stick and rules those parts out.

Comment: You can also have a look at [Here][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/540956/cannot-create-restore-point-on-windows-7-64-bit-the-specified-object-was-not-f/541025#541025

This might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Hal.dll is a file critical to logging on to Windows.

Try checking the drive for errors - a guide is available [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Check-a-drive-for-errors).